# How do I send data from Excel to SQL temp tables for processing using VBA?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

My group uses an Excel macro-based tool to do some serious number crunching. I would like to move the number-crunching bit to SQL because using VBA has become intolerable due to the runtime. Users need to be able to use Excel as the interface and also need to be able to run their macros simultaneously as the Excel workbook is self-contained. I've been testing my plan to call an SQL stored procedure from VBA to pull the data from Excel into SQL temp tables, crunch it, and send it back to Excel. I'm able to pull the data from Excel if I run my SP in SQL Management Studio. Here is the SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_test_import
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@path varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare  @SQL varchar(2500);
set @SQL = '
select *
from openrowset(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
  ''Excel 12.0 Macro;
   Database='+@path+''',
   [Sheet1$]); '

create table [#test](
    col1 varchar(15),
    col2 varchar(15),
    col3 varchar(15),
    col4 varchar(15)
)

insert into #test
exec(@SQL)

select * from #mb_test
END
```

So that works fine. I then try to call this SP from the Excel file containing the data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ado_test()

Dim adoConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim connectString As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim sPath As String

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
sPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

'-Create a new ADO connection --
Set adoConnection = New ADODB.Connection
'-Create a new ADO recordset --
Set adoRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

'-Build our connection string to use when we open the connection --

connectString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;DATABASE=testDB"
adoConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 20
adoConnection.CommandTimeout = 20

adoConnection.Open connectString
strSQL = "EXEC testDB.dbo.sp_test_import " & vbCr _
            & "@path = " & "'" & sPath & "'"

adoRecordset.Open strSQL, adoConnection

End Sub
```

The code hangs on the 'adoRecordset.Open' call. If I instead pass a path to a separate Excel file in the variable @path, then everything works swimmingly. Is there a simple way that I can make this SP call from the same workbook? I'm not worried about security since the SQL db will be a dedicated structure for pulling in and processing temporary data. I just need users to be able to run their Excel tools whenever they want to, so I don't want to use permanent tables in the DB in case their respective inputs get mixed up together.

Everything I've found online deals with ASP or ISS and I know nothing about ASP and ISS doesn't seem like the right solution to my particular problem. I could have VBA pass the data to external text files and then pass the paths to those text files to the SQL SP, but if there is a cleaner solution then I would like to know about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some reason not to just use ADO to run your SQL on the excel workbook rather than loading it into a database first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are passing in `strSQL`, a `String` data type, as the first parameter of the `.Open` method, but the `Open` method requires a `Command` object (according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

What you'll want to do is declare an `ADODB.Command` object and pass that through.  I've modified your code to do this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ado_test()

    Dim adoConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim adoRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim adoCommand As ADODB.Command
    Dim connectString As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim sPath As String

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    '-Create a new ADO connection --'
    Set adoConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    '-Create a new ADO recordset --'
    Set adoRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    '-Create a new ADO command --'
    Set adoCommand = New ADODB.Command

    '-Build our connection string to use when we open the connection --'

    connectString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;DATABASE=testDB"
    adoConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 20
    adoConnection.CommandTimeout = 20

    adoConnection.Open connectString
    strSQL = "sp_test_import"

    With adoCommand
        .ActiveConnection = adoConnection
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .Parameters.Refresh
        .Parameters(1).Value = sPath
    End With

    Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute

    If adoRecordset.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset adoRecordset
    '--adoRecordset.Open adoCommand, adoConnection'

    '--Close the database connection'
    adoConnection.Close

End Sub
```

More information on the [Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502(v=vs.85).aspx) object.

I also added how I get values from SQL Server into the Excel workbook using the `CopyFromRecordset` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, Joshua. I've tested your code and I get the following error:  "cannot change the activeconnection property of a recordset object which has a command object"... any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: Oh sorry, I will update.  Completely escaped me that you are doing a stored procedure.

Comment: I updated my answer, I will try and test really quick with my own database to be sure it runs as I figured.  I also added how I extract the values from the recordset into the workbook using the `CopyFromRecordset` method.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you, it's still timing out for me with the error "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Query timeout expired". Maybe it has something to do with my system if it works for you. Everything is on the server itself (excel file, db), so I wouldn't think it would be a firewall issue but maybe it's something in my SQL Server config?

Comment: Also thanks for the info on the Command object and CopyFromRecordset method!

Comment: No problem.  I substituted a stored procedure on my machine in for yours and it ran fine and put the data into Excel.  The only thing I can think of is to check in your SQL Server there may be a connection timeout that trumps the one declared in Excel.  Your connection string might be incorrect?  Mine was `Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=SERVERNAME,1433;Database=DATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;`.  The `1433` is the default port, you may or may not need to specify that.

Comment: I'm going to try setting up a SQL server installation on a different machine. My connection string is right as I can pull the data from a different Excel file into SQL, just not from the file running the macro. It must have something to do with the server itself since it works for you. Thanks again for your help!